# What could stop Redis from serving keys content (nodejs)?

Tags: node.js, redis

I'm using Redis in my nodejs server, communicating with a browser html/js application. Under conditions I can't identify, my server gets stuck. It throws no errors, keep to be alive and responding, but can't get values from Redis. This is (the simplified version) how the connection with Redis is established.

```
var Stash   = require('redis'),
    Sockjs  = require('sockjs')
stash = Stash.createClient(some_port,some_host);
sockjs = Sockjs.createServer(); 

var Instances = {
  get: function (id, cb) {
     stash.get('something_' + id, cb)
}

sockjs = Sockjs.createServer(); 
sockjs.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.on('data', function(data) {
    var id = somecorrectid;
    Instances.get(id, function(err, instance) { /*Here the magic happens*/ }
  }
}
```

Now, this works perfectly in normal conditions. 
When the issue happens, the code between the last brackets isn't executed anymore, no matter how many times I fire again the event triggering the piece of code (that is a post data throught a socket) and from what client. Redis, in the meanwhile, is alive and rocking. Redis-cli is responding. The key searched with the 'get' exist and it is correct in its form. My server is still able to write keys to Redis correctly, but seems it can't read them anymore. This have no sense to me, and it is difficult to investigate or have more informations for I can't get how to replicate the issue. Any clue?

Comment: how many clients usually you have connected, running this operation ?

Comment: can you include some of the outer code that defines the event and describe the conditions under which it is called?

Comment: In debug phase, one or two clients and seems enough to cause the issue. I include some code. The event is the arrival of messages sent by the client in post. (The code is not complete, it would be too complicated, is only to give an idea. Logging during the issue, I have the idea that the problem lays exactly at this point of the code)

Comment: if you put a console.log in the first line of the on "data" handler does it get called when you expect? also, just to be safe, in that lowest on "data" scope 'id' isn't defined, do you mean to use data.id or something else there?

Comment: Oh, yes sorry. The log gets called and the id is correct. I put a lot a log inside the code now, to have more informations. The problem is having to wait that the issue happens again, for I do not know how to force it to happen.